# Breakpoints not hit while debugging c++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile, breakpoints

**System:** POP OS
**IDE:** Visual Studio Code

I am attempting to debug a simple c++ project. When I initially set up the project, the debugger would function as expected. When I added a makefile, breakpoints were no longer hit. Before adding the makefile I compiled from a task.json file with **g++ -g -o main.o main.cpp**. This command obviously didn't do what the makefile is doing, but debugging DID work in my environment.

Setting launch.json to stopAtEntry also does not work. So my assumption is that I am compiling incorrectly.

**Makefile output:**

g++ -Wall -I./header -L./lib   -c -o source/MqttManager.o source/MqttManager.cpp

g++ -g -o bin/debug/GenericMqttClient source/main.o source/MqttManager.o -Wall -I./header -L./lib  -lpaho-mqtt3c

rm -r ./source/*.o

Here are the relevant files:

**launch.json**

```
   {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/debug/GenericMqttClient",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++
EXENAME = GenericMqttClient

#   Directories
HDIR = ./header
LDIR = ./lib
ODIR = ./obj
SDIR = ./source
BIN = ./bin
DEBUGDIR = $(BIN)/debug
RELDIR = $(BIN)/release

# Project Files
SRC = $(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

# Includes
DEPS = $(HDIR)/MqttManager.h
LIBS = -lpaho-mqtt3c

#flags
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -I$(HDIR) -L$(LDIR)
# DEBUGFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) -g

# Object files
$(SDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# Release
release: prep $(RELDIR)/$(EXENAME) objclean
$(RELDIR)/$(EXENAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^  $(CXXFLAGS) $(LIBS) 

# Debug
debug: prep $(DEBUGDIR)/$(EXENAME) objclean
$(DEBUGDIR)/$(EXENAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -g -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)  $(LIBS)

#
#   Other Rules
#
all: clean debug release objclean

prep:
    @mkdir -p $(DEBUGDIR) $(RELDIR)

objclean:
    rm -r $(SDIR)/*.o

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN)/*
```

Let me know if I should include more files.

Comment: _"At some point between initially setting the project up, and creating a makefile, breakpoints stopped being hit. I assume that it's due either to my makefile or config as it was previously working. But I am stumped."_ This is why you should be using **version control** so you can simply go back in time to remind yourself what you changed. It's been basic standard practice now for, what, 30 years?

Comment: I am using version control. And I am aware of what changed: the makefile. Im just not clear on why breakpoints are not being hit as I am compiling with -g.

Comment: Okay, so you know more than you told us! You don't just know _that_ the makefile changed; you also know _how_ it changed, so that should be the focus of your question...

Comment: Thanks. I edited with more details.

Comment: That's better - we have enough to go on now.

Comment: Using g++ -g -o main.o main.cpp command before running debugger did worked for me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to give g++ the `-g` switch when compiling your CPP files. Now you don't. It'll need to be added back in.

The way you've written the Makefile, you could uncomment the definition of `DEBUGFLAGS`, then change `$(CXXFLAGS)` to `$(DEBUGFLAGS)` in your `$(SDIR)/%.o` target. However, this would affect release builds too, so you probably want to find a different way to do this, such as by replacing the `CXXFLAGS` definition just for the `debug` target (which should also affect its dependencies):

```
debug: CXXFLAGS=$(DEBUGFLAGS)
debug: prep $(DEBUGDIR)/$(EXENAME) objclean
$(DEBUGDIR)/$(EXENAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)  $(LIBS)
```

I've also removed the `-g` from the link stage. The switch needs to be given at the compilation stage (*not* the link stage, which is performed by the `debug` target) because it is responsible for writing debugging information into your program. This can only be generated from source code and, without it, your debugger has no way to honour breakpoints.

---

**tl;dr**

In the resulting commands you've quoted, you need to make it so that `-g` is moved, from the second command to the first:

```
g++ -Wall -I./header -L./lib -c -o source/MqttManager.o source/MqttManager.cpp
g++ -g -o bin/debug/GenericMqttClient source/main.o source/MqttManager.o -Wall -I./header -L./lib -lpaho-mqtt3c
rm -r ./source/*.o
```